# Returning the column header of max value on per row basis

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

I have a spreadsheet whereby on a monthly basis I need to return the top product based on a table for that month. I have copied a screenshot of my current setup below.

[image]

I am currently doing this by creating an additional column (column `H`) which uses the `INDEX`, `MATCH` and `MAX` functions to return the name of the highest product in that row.

I then use another `INDEX` `MATCH` as a lookup in cells `K4` and `L4` to return the value for that month.

The problem is that my table expands each month as a new row is added and I wanted to find out if there was a way to combine both the formulas into one. So that all I would need to do is update the current and previous months in cells `K3` and `L3`. I have the same setup across quite a few sheets so want to automate as much as possible.

Would love some help, ideally without using VBA if possible at all.

Comment: Can you clarify please what you need? You need formulas for `K4` and `L4` based on month in `K2` and `L2` to get top products?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm after.

Comment: but why not: `=Index($H:$H,MATCH($A:$A,K3,0))` for `k4` and drag it across to `L4`?

Comment: Thanks for that but it returns an error(#N/A), possibly because we don't have a column reference for the INDEX function(?).

I wanted to see if there is a way to eliminate the Top products column and combine that as one?

Comment: sorry, mistype:) correct one: `=Index($H:$H,MATCH(K3,$A:$A,0))`

Comment: Thanks for that. that works. is there a way to circumvent the lookup via top product at all?

Comment: Did you mean remove column H?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this formula in `K4` and drag it across to `L4`:

`=INDEX($B1:$H1,1,MATCH(MAX(INDEX($B:$H,MATCH(K2,$A:$A,0),0)),INDEX($B:$H,MATCH(K2,$A:$A,0),0),0))`