# Get the attributes name with highest value in RapidMiner

Tags: attributes, max, rapidminer

I want to generate a new attribute where the attribute name(s) that has highest value is stored. My goal is similar like this question ([Returning the column header of max value on per row basis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019826/excel-returning-the-column-header-of-max-value-on-per-row-basis)).

Answer (score 0):

It's quite complicated and involves transposing each example within an example set, sorting to find the maximum, extracting the name of the attribute into a macro and setting this value into the original example set.

Here's a process that you can copy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="6.5.000">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="6.5.000" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <parameter key="logverbosity" value="init"/>
    <parameter key="random_seed" value="2001"/>
    <parameter key="send_mail" value="never"/>
    <parameter key="notification_email" value=""/>
    <parameter key="process_duration_for_mail" value="30"/>
    <parameter key="encoding" value="SYSTEM"/>
    <parameter key="parallelize_main_process" value="false"/>
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="generate_data" compatibility="6.5.000" expanded="true" height="60" name="Generate Data" width="90" x="112" y="75">
        <parameter key="target_function" value="random"/>
        <parameter key="number_examples" value="100"/>
        <parameter key="number_of_attributes" value="5"/>
        <parameter key="attributes_lower_bound" value="-10.0"/>
        <parameter key="attributes_upper_bound" value="10.0"/>
        <parameter key="use_local_random_seed" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="local_random_seed" value="1992"/>
        <parameter key="datamanagement" value="double_array"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="generate_attributes" compatibility="6.5.000" expanded="true" height="76" name="Generate Attributes" width="90" x="246" y="75">
        <list key="function_descriptions">
          <parameter key="maximum" value="&quot;unknown&quot;"/>
        </list>
        <parameter key="keep_all" value="true"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="loop_examples" compatibility="6.5.000" expanded="true" height="76" name="Loop Examples" width="90" x="380" y="75">
        <parameter key="iteration_macro" value="example"/>
        <parameter key="parallelize_example_process" value="false"/>
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="filter_example_range" compatibility="6.5.000" expanded="true" height="76" name="Filter Example Range" width="90" x="112" y="30">
            <parameter key="first_example" value="%{example}"/>
            <parameter key="last_example" value="%{example}"/>
            <parameter key="invert_filter" value="false"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="select_attributes" compatibility="6.5.000" expanded="true" height="76" name="Select Attributes" width="90" x="112" y="165">
            <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="subset"/>
            <parameter key="attribute" value=""/>
            <parameter key="attributes" value="id|label|maximum"/>
            <parameter key="use_except_expression" value="false"/>
            <parameter key="value_type" value="attribute_value"/>
            <parameter key="use_value_type_exception" value="false"/>
            <parameter key="except_value_type" value="time"/>
            <parameter key="block_type" value="attribute_block"/>
            <parameter key="use_block_type_exception" value="false"/>
            <parameter key="except_block_type" value="value_matrix_row_start"/>
            <parameter key="invert_selection" value="true"/>
            <parameter key="include_special_attributes" value="true"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="transpose" compatibility="6.5.000" expanded="true" height="76" name="Transpose" width="90" x="246" y="165"/>
          <operator activated="true" class="sort" compatibility="6.5.000" expanded="true" height="76" name="Sort" width="90" x="380" y="165">
            <parameter key="attribute_name" value="att_1"/>
            <parameter key="sorting_direction" value="decreasing"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="extract_macro" compatibility="6.5.000" expanded="true" height="60" name="Extract Macro" width="90" x="514" y="165">
            <parameter key="macro" value="max"/>
            <parameter key="macro_type" value="data_value"/>
            <parameter key="statistics" value="average"/>
            <parameter key="attribute_name" value="id"/>
            <parameter key="example_index" value="1"/>
            <list key="additional_macros"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="subprocess" compatibility="6.5.000" expanded="true" height="94" name="Subprocess" width="90" x="648" y="30">
            <parameter key="parallelize_nested_process" value="false"/>
            <process expanded="true">
              <connect from_port="in 1" to_port="out 1"/>
              <portSpacing port="source_in 1" spacing="0"/>
              <portSpacing port="source_in 2" spacing="0"/>
              <portSpacing port="source_in 3" spacing="0"/>
              <portSpacing port="sink_out 1" spacing="0"/>
              <portSpacing port="sink_out 2" spacing="0"/>
            </process>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="set_data" compatibility="6.5.000" expanded="true" height="76" name="Set Data" width="90" x="782" y="30">
            <parameter key="example_index" value="%{example}"/>
            <parameter key="count_backwards" value="false"/>
            <parameter key="attribute_name" value="maximum"/>
            <parameter key="value" value="%{max}"/>
            <list key="additional_values"/>
          </operator>
          <connect from_port="example set" to_op="Filter Example Range" to_port="example set input"/>
          <connect from_op="Filter Example Range" from_port="example set output" to_op="Select Attributes" to_port="example set input"/>
          <connect from_op="Filter Example Range" from_port="original" to_op="Subprocess" to_port="in 1"/>
          <connect from_op="Select Attributes" from_port="example set output" to_op="Transpose" to_port="example set input"/>
          <connect from_op="Transpose" from_port="example set output" to_op="Sort" to_port="example set input"/>
          <connect from_op="Sort" from_port="example set output" to_op="Extract Macro" to_port="example set"/>
          <connect from_op="Extract Macro" from_port="example set" to_op="Subprocess" to_port="in 2"/>
          <connect from_op="Subprocess" from_port="out 1" to_op="Set Data" to_port="example set input"/>
          <connect from_op="Set Data" from_port="example set output" to_port="example set"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_example set" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_example set" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_output 1" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Generate Data" from_port="output" to_op="Generate Attributes" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Generate Attributes" from_port="example set output" to_op="Loop Examples" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="Loop Examples" from_port="example set" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```